# Regex to match alphanumeric codes

Tags: regex

I want to have a regex which matches the following  pattern

- 1st character Alphanumeric excluding **I,O,S,Z**
- 2-3rd character Alphanumeric
- 4th-5th character only one of these **BB,KA,JQ**

Currently I have developed this pattern

```
[^I,O,S,Z,i,o,s,z][0-9A-Za-z]{2}[AA|TN|TP]{2}
```

But it is taking into account `AI2AT` which it should not.

Comment: `/^[A-HJ-NP-RT-Y0-9][0-9A-Z]{2}(?:BB|KA|JQ)$/i`

Comment: If you provide the regex flavor (what is the programming language?) there could appear other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[0-9A-HJ-NP-RT-Y][A-Z0-9]{2}(?:BB|KA|JQ)$/i
```

or

```
/^[0-9A-Ha-hJ-Nj-nP-Rp-rT-Yt-y][A-Z0-9]{2}(?:BB|KA|JQ)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG0pK0/1)

If you can use lookaheads, you may use

```
/^(?![IOSZiosz])[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2}(?:BB|KA|JQ)$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG0pK0/2)

Your current `[^I,O,S,Z,i,o,s,z][0-9A-Za-z]{2}[AA|TN|TP]{2}` expression actually does not check for a string start/end, the `[^I,O,S,Z,i,o,s,z]` negated character class matches any char but `I`, `,`, `O`, etc., and the `[AA|TN|TP]{2}` character class matches either `A`, `|`, `T`, `N`, `P`, two times.

So,

- Instead of the first negated character class you can use `[0-9A-HJ-NP-RT-Y]`
- Instead of the last character class, use a *non-capturing group* `(?:...)` with alternation operators `|` (that are treated as a literal symbol `|` inside `[...]` character classes)
- The case insensitive modifier helps "shrink" the pattern  a bit, but you can double the lowercase letters with uppercase counterparts if you cannot use it
- The `(?![IOSZiosz])` *negative lookahead* restricts a generic alphanumeric `[A-Za-z0-9]` pattern so that it could not match either `I`, `i`, `o`, `O`, `S`, `s`, `z`  or `Z`.

Comment: Note that in Java, you could use `^[A-Za-z&&[^IOSZiosz]][A-Za-z0-9]{2}(?:BB|KA|JQ)$` and in .NET - `^[A-Za-z-[IOSZiosz]][A-Za-z0-9]{2}(?:BB|KA|JQ)$`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks this was what I was looking for

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew also can we use the non-capturing group (?:...)  for [0-9A-HJ-NP-RT-Y] like not (?:I|O|S|Z) ??

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve with a non-capturing group. It is only used to group subpatterns, it still *matches* and *consumes* text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have a constraint on the length of the regex, that's why I was wondering if it was possible to use the group or not to shorten the length. Anyways, Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why a constraint on the pattern length? What is the environment? Note it is not a good idea to shorten regex patterns, that might lead to unwelcome results. BTW, `/^[0-9A-HJ-NP-RT-Y][A-Z0-9]{2}(?:BB|KA|JQ)$/i` will also match `9a1bb` (where `bb` is lowercase).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! the constraint on length is no longer required

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?!I,O,S,Z,i,o,s,z)[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]{2}(BB|KA|JQ){2}
```